# How to store multiple instances of a preference in a IPreferenceStore?

Tags: java, eclipse, preferences, store

I would like to store the parameters of multiple complex items in an eclipse application as preferences, which already uses IPreferenceStore as its preference store.
For one item I would like to store multiple parameters.
Do we have some built-in method to store multiple instances and manipulate them as a java list, or should I resort to one of the following workarounds:

- a preference storing the number of items, and a naming convention, like

  "mypreference.numitems" -> 2

  "mypreference.0.foo" -> ...

  "mypreference.0.bar" -> ...

  "mypreference.1.foo" -> ...

  ...
- serialize the whole array into one value in a preference (brr...)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the later method and often use it. Have a look at `PreferenceConverter` for the similar conversions for some of the standard types like `Color` and `Font`...

In a few cases, where I need to save even more complex structures, I have used JSON-encoded values. Pretty easy!

Comment: You can also use `XMLMemento` to write out a `String` and extract out the information when you read it.